# tabBtn addEventListener click not triggering alert

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make this HTML menu work properly.

For some reason when it tries to do a forEach the tabBtn addEventListener 'click' is not alerting my pop up. Anyone have any ideas why?

```js
// Navigation Menu
const btnLeft = document.querySelector(".left-btn");
const btnRight = document.querySelector(".right-btn");
const tabMenu = document.querySelector(".tab-menu");
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
const tabBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-btn");

const IconVisability = () => {
  let scrollLeftValue = Math.ceil(tabMenu.scrollLeft);

  let scrollableWidth =
    tabMenu.scrollWidth - tabMenu.clientWidth;

  btnLeft.style.display = scrollLeftValue > 0 ? "block" : "none";
  btnRight.style.display =
    scrollableWidth > scrollLeftValue ? "block" : "none";
};

const tab_Nav = function (tabBtnClick) {
  tabBtns.forEach(tabBtn => {
    tabBtn.classList.remove("active");
  });

  tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.classList.remove("active");
  });

  tabBtns[tabBtnClick].classList.add("active");
  tabs[tabBtnClick].classList.add("active");
};

//Draggable nativation
let activeDrag = false;

tabBtns.forEach((tabBtn, index) => {
  tabBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //  tab_Nav(index);

    alert(index);
  });
});

tabMenu.addEventListener("mousemove", drag => {
  if (!activeDrag) return;
  tabMenu.scrollLeft -= drag.movementX;
  IconVisability();
  tabMenu.classList.add("dragging");
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  activeDrag = false;
  tabMenu.classList.remove("dragging");
});

tabMenu.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
  activeDrag = true;
});

btnRight.addEventListener("click", () => {
  tabMenu.scrollLeft += 200;
  setTimeout(() => IconVisability(), 50);
});

btnLeft.addEventListener("click", () => {
  tabMenu.scrollLeft -= 200;
  setTimeout(() => IconVisability(), 50);
});

window.onload = function () {
  btnRight.style.display =
    tabMenu.scrollWidth > tabMenu.clientWidth ||
    tabMenu.scrollWidth >= window.innerWidth
      ? "block"
      : "none";
  btnLeft.style.display =
    tabMenu.scrollWidth >= window.innerWidth ? "" : "none";
};

window.onresize = function () {
  btnRight.style.display =
    tabMenu.scrollWidth > tabMenu.clientWidth ||
    tabMenu.scrollWidth >= window.innerWidth
      ? "block"
      : "none";
  btnLeft.style.display =
    tabMenu.scrollWidth >= window.innerWidth ? "" : "none";

  let scrollLeftValue = Math.round(tabMenu.scrollLeft);

  btnLeft.style.display = scrollLeftValue > 0 ? "block" : "none";
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.tab-nav-bar {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.tab-navigation {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tab-menu {
  color: var(--text-color);
  list-style: none;
  background: #2c677d;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.tab-menu.dragging {
  scroll-behavior: unset;
  cursor: grab;
}

.tab-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.tab-btn {
  color: #f7f3f3 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: #2c677d;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}

.tab-menu.dragging .tab-btn {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tab-btn:hover {
  background: #71afc5;
  z-index: 999;
}

.tab-btn.active {
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #2c677d, 1px -1px 0 #2c677d, -1px 1px 0 #2c677d, 1px 1px 0 #2c677d !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #71afc5;
  z-index: 999;
}

.left-btn,
.right-btn {
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 1.8em;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left-btn {
  padding: 4.5px;
  left: 0;
  background: #2c677d;
}

.right-btn {
  padding: 4.5px;
  right: 0;
  background: #2c677d;
}

.tab-content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(25px);
  content-visibility: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.tab.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
  content-visibility: visible;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="tab-nav-bar">
    <div class="tab-navigation">
      <i class="uil uil-angle-left left-btn"></i>
      <i class="uil uil-angle-right right-btn"></i>
      <ul class="tab-menu">
        <li class="tab-btn">General</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Immunizations</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test3 Longer</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test4 Longer</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test5 Longer</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test6 Longer</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test7 Longer</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test8 Longer</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test6 Longer</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test7 Longer</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test8 Longer</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test6 Longer</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test7 Longer</li>
        <li class="tab-btn">Test8 Longer</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab">
      <div>
        TEST1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <div>
        TEST2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I am expecting each time I click the tab it alerts so then I can set the tab to active while turning off the other tabs.

Comment: Update:  When I remove the code for dragging (mousemove, mouseup, mousedown) I get an alert.  I would like to allow dragging of the menu but this is at least functioning without the dragging.  Anyone has any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see any [tag:angularjs] here so I'm removing that tag.

Comment: You should remove any reference to the 'tabs' inside the tab_Nav function, since they are based on different indexes.

Comment: Also, in the code you've shared every single button seems to be working fine and alerting the correct index.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis I had to remove the 'dragging' ability code:

tabMenu.addEventListener("mousemove", drag => {
  if (!activeDrag) return;
  tabMenu.scrollLeft -= drag.movementX;
  IconVisability();
  tabMenu.classList.add("dragging");
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  activeDrag = false;
  tabMenu.classList.remove("dragging");
});

For some reason inside of the app that I am using this in - it caused it to completely break.  Removing this functionality and then I get my alerts.  Strange, but yea.